# Problems with filezilla and ubuntu

Tags: ftp, filezilla, ubuntu-12.10

I have a big problem with my FileZilla on my current Ubuntu 12.10 installation so its unusable. First of all some facts:

- FileZilla works with my Router/WLan etc. setup on windows perfectly.
- It even worked on Ubuntu before upgrading (allthough I'm not sure if it affects at first 12.04 or 12.10)
- So the Problem I guess is related to my Ubuntu

The problems are the following:

- it's slow
- I often have connection timeouts while transfering a couple of files or often when changing directories
- often files get transferred without their contents
- furthermore if bigger uploads timeout or stop I cannot determine what has allready been uploaded because it does not seem to follow any order subdirectorywise.

I'm kind of a Linux beginner too so I have no idea what I can do about this. Hopefully anybody can help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I encountered the same problem with you. It's all right using FileZilla on Windows, but unstable on Ubuntu. Frequent timeout after MSLD command occurred.

I solved the problem by using the `ftp` command instead. It's built-in and rather simple. You could also check if the ftp connection is OK in Ubuntu with this tool. If it is, then it might be something wrong with FileZilla. (I guess)

I wrote an article about this: http://pengwenqiang.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/the-usage-of-the-basic-ftp-command-in-linux/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow after i made an update the problems where gone entirely and i had a couple of happy weeks. But out of nowhere they returned again, so maybe i'll try your solution but i'd prefer a working version of filezilla

Comment: I used to use FileZilla as well. But after a trial on the command line ftp, I felt much more comfortable. It's a small and stable program that you know what is going on, and without worrying about the inconsistent behavior after an update. Honestly to say, I lost my confidence with FileZilla. These guys in the FileZilla Forum   tend to treat all the problems are firewall or router related problem, not theirs, which certainly is not always the truth. @patman